# Choosing a Username for creating a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

When I create a Google Cloud Compute Engine Debian/Linux VM instance a 'default' username (the one I find in Metadata -> SSHkeys similar to firstname_lastname) is generated/created in the Debian instance. Is it possible letting generate/create another user eg. vmadmin? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add new username/SSH key pair in Metadata -> SSH Keys section or just log into an instance and provide a new username like this:

`gcloud compute ssh USER@my-instance`

Corresponding new entry for USER will be injected into Metadata -> SSH Keys and USER will be created on all instances by default.

Also, check out [User Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts) if you need more structured approach to maintain users on VMs.